# QMail Problem: Can't send email to one specific domain

Tags: email

I'm running qmail as part of a Plesk installation on a Debian server. Everything works fine apart from any emails sent to @nandos.co.uk.

I get no error messages they just end up stuck in the queue for eternity.

I have no idea what is going on, because as far as I can tell this is the ONLY domain the server won't send emails to.

Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you need to check the logs to find out what QMail is seeing when it tries to deliver e-mail to that domain.

Additionally, you may wish to try to manually send an e-mail from the QMail box to the remote mail server.  To do that, perform the following steps:

Find the actual mail server handling mail for example.com by running the following command from a command prompt (replacing example.com with the domain you are having problems with):

```
foo@bar$ host -t mx example.com
```

In response to that query, you'll get one or more responses of the form:

```
example.com mail is handled by 20 mail.example.com.
example.com mail is handled by 30 mail.example.com.
example.com mail is handled by 10 mail.example.com.
```

These are the mail servers designated for this domain.  You'll want to take the hostname with the **lowest** number to work with in our next step.  (If you get back the answer that example.com has no MX record, then just use the original hostname/domain name as your mail destination for below.)

Next we'll use telnet to manually connect to the mail server and attempt to send an e-mail.  In the example below, I will indent the response lines the server is sending back with a few extra spaces to help clarify what you should type, and what you might get back (note, there will be some slight variation depending on mail server software).

```
foo@bar$ telnet mail.example.com 25

  Trying 10.1.1.1...
  Connected to mail.example.com.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  220 ****************************************
HELO your-source-hostname-here.example.org
  250 mail.example.com
MAIL FROM: <foo@example.com>
  250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <bar@example.com>
  250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From: Foo <foo@example.com>
To: Bar <bar@example.com>
Subject: Foo -> Bar Test

This is a test e-mail from Foo to Bar.
.
  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BE0D91F459
quit
  221 2.0.0 Bye
  Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Note at the end there it gave a response of `250` and `Ok`.  That line is signifying that the e-mail was accepted for delivery.  If it had given a different response code, that would help indicate what the problem might be.  The mail server might also offer additional details on the problem, as well.

Don't forget to replace e-mail addresses and hostnames with the valid and appropriate entries for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for errors. You can search through the /var/log directory to locate them or google for "qmail log files" to see if you can get some help finding them (maybe [this site](http://qmail.jms1.net/logfiles.shtml) helps?)

Once you have an error code from the logs you can google that and see what the next step is. Without a proper error from the MTA there's not much anyone here can do...first step is finding the root error :-)

Answer (score 0):

Standard location for logs in `/var/log/qmail`.  You want to look at the logs for `qmail-send`.

If it is not clear and you provide the output, I should be able to provide a specific recommendation.